# How to efficiently loop through matrix elements

Tags: matlab, if-statement, matrix

I have a matlab script for 8-bit image analysis and I'm trying to enhance objects in the image by subtracting the background with no objects present. What I want to do at a pixel level is:

```
if B-I>50 then E=I
else E=255-B-I
```

Where, `B` is the background, `I` the image and `E` my enhanced image. I know I can do this by looping through each element of the image matrix by the following:

```
diff=imsubtract(B,I);
nrows=1024;
ncols=1360;
for r=1:nrows
     for c=1:ncols
         if diff(r,c)>50
             E=I(r,c);
         else
             E=255-diff(r,c);
         end
     end
 end
```

But is this rather slow when going multiple images. I've also tried the follow:

```
 E=255-diff;
 E(diff>50)=I;
```

But receive the following error:

In an assignment  `A(I) = B`, the
number of elements in B and I must
be the same.

Any tips on optimizing this would be greatly apprenticed!

Comment: Do NOT use `diff` as a variable name. It is a standard function in matlab which gets overloaded this way. This can be confusing and lead to unexpected problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> In an assignment A(I) = B, the number of elements in B and I must be
>   the same.

The reason for this error is that you are trying to assign all the content of `I` to a subset of `E` (those pixels where `diff>50`).  You have to specifically tell MATLAB that you want those pixels set to the matching pixels in `I`.

```
E(diff>50)=I(diff>50);
```

Incidentally you should be careful using `imsubtract` here.  For pixels where `I` has a higher value than `B`, that will result in zeros (if your values are `uint8`).  It may be okay (not 100% clear if you're looking for the absolute difference or really just where `B` is larger than `I`)

Comment: This works exactly like I wanted
    E=255-D;
    E(D>50)=I(D>50);

Changed to variable to D as per one of the other comments about using diff.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What if you use use [find()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/find.html)

```
ind = find(B-I>50)
E(ind) = I(ind)

% And then the ones that are not `B-I>50`
E(~ind) = 255-B(~ind)-I(~ind)
```

Comment: Actually you can leave out `find` and directly use `ind = B-I>50`, that should make things more efficient.

Comment: You are probably right. It's just that the OP tried using logcal indexing and it failed. That's why I used find.

Comment: Tested this but results in E as a 1x1392640 matrix instead of 1024x1360.

Comment: I am assuming that you have pre-allocated `E`. `E = zeros(size(I))`. If you have, then E should have the same shape as `I`

Comment: although I think @nkjt answer is more elegant and probably the most effective and fastest one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this vectorized approach that uses logical indexing. I could not test it out on images though, so would be great if that's taken care of.

**Code**

```
diff1=double(imsubtract(B,I));
E = double(I).*(diff1>50) + (255-diff1).*(diff1<=50);
```

You might be needed to convert the datatype back to unsigned integer formats as used for images.